# `xlsxwriter` Line Transparency does not work unless color is changed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

From the documentation I see that it is possible to use transparency for chart areas. I was wondering if transparency for line charts is supported in XlsxWriter. The syntax :

```
chart.add_series({
    'name': 'something',
    'categories': [<excel range>],
    'values': [<excel range>],
    'line':   {'color': 'yellow','transparency': 25},
})
```

shows my line chart in yellow. However, there is no transparency.

So, is transparency possible for line charts? if so, what's the proper syntax?

I'm running Excel 2016 on Python 3.6.3. Also maybe worth mentioning is how I use xlsxwriter:

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='xlsxwriter', datetime_format='dd-mmm-yy')
```

## UPDATE:

Running the code from the accepted answer yields the desired output:
[image]
however, if there is no color parameter used in the line construction, the transparency will not work:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    # Create a new Chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Write some data to add to plot on the chart.
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
    [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
]

worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C1', data[2])

# Configure the charts. In simplest case we just add some data series.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5',
                  'line':   {'width':0.25,'transparency': 25}})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('A7', chart)

workbook.close()
```

As a check I replaced the color parameter for the width parameter, in fact our line shows the correct width but there is no transparency:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't documented but it is supported:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Create a new Chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

# Write some data to add to plot on the chart.
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
    [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
]

worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B1', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C1', data[2])

# Configure the charts. In simplest case we just add some data series.
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$5',
                  'line':   {'color': 'yellow',
                             'transparency': 25}})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('A7', chart)

workbook.close()
```

Output (see that the gridlines are partially visible through the yellow line):

[image]

**Update:** It is [documented](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html#chart-formatting-line) now.

**Update 2:**

> however, if there is no color parameter used in the line construction, the transparency will not work:

This is the default behaviour in Excel. It isn't possible to turn on transparency without specifying a colour. This is because internally the transparency is stored as a percentage of the alpha value for the colour, for example:

```
        <a:ln>
          <a:solidFill>
            <a:srgbClr val="4F81BD">
              <a:alpha val="50000"/>
            </a:srgbClr>
          </a:solidFill>
        </a:ln>
```

This isn't obvious in the interface of Excel 2015 and later although you can see that the the line changes from "Automatic" to "Solid Line" when you change the Transparency. In older versions of Excel it was clearer that you had to specify a Solid Color before changing the transparency.

I'll update the XlsxWriter documentation to highlight this. As a workaround the user should specify a colour when changing the transparency.

Comment: Interesting @jmcnamara However the following code does not produce a line chart with transparency:

`
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart.add_series({
        'name': 'Russell 2000',
        'categories': ['Sheet1', 1 , 24 + offset, bound, 24 + offset],
        'values': ['Sheet1', 1 , 25 + offset, bound, 25 + offset],
        'line':   {'width': 1.5, 'transparency':25},
        'y2_axis':    y2_axis,
    })
`
I would paste the excel result but I'm a noob lol. As a check I modify the width. The transparency parameter remains at 0 but the line width is in fact 1.5 pt

Comment: Hi @jmcnamara any thoughts on this? As I mentioned, your solution does not work given my current implementation

Comment: Open a new issue with some **complete working** sample code that demonstrates the issue and I'll take a look. Also ensure that you are on a recent version of XlsxWriter.

Comment: Will work on a dummy script soon, thank you for your patience

Comment: We've observed that the `transparency` parameter does not take effect unless the `color` parameter is also used.

Comment: @billyjmc. That sounds like a bug. Can you open a bug report against XlsxWriter with a small example program that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: I’m still waiting for someone to open a reproducible bug report.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot!

Comment: I updated my original question @jmcnamara since I don't know how to generate a bug report. Happy to do so if someone points me in the right direction

Comment: I've added a bug report: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/544

Comment: Added an update about the bug report. Basically this is the default behaviour of Excel.